# Can I use jQuery.post() with LiveServerTestCase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, casperjs, django-testing

I'm writing a test using a LiveServerTestCase, django-casper, and casperjs for a view that includes javascript. Half way through a client side script I have a jQuery.post(url, callback_function(r){}) line.

When callback_function is called during a test r is null. However, when I run the application normally and step through the same javascript when callback_function is called r has the expected value.

This makes me think that there is a detail about LiveServerTestCase I'm missing to get jQuery.post to work with it. Can anybody please shed light on what I should do next to debug this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because the static files aren't around. In Django 1.7, LiveServerTestCase no longer supported serving up the static files. It was moved into [testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase)

Try changing your test classes to subclass `StaticLiveServerTestCase`.